# spark onQueryProgress duplicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-structured-streaming

When I monitor structured streaming use StreamingQueryListener, I found duplicate in on onQueryProgress

```
  override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {

        if(queryProgress.progress.numInputRows!=0) {

          println("Query made progress: " + queryProgress.progress)

        }
```

the result is

```
Query made progress: {
  "id" : "e76a8789-738c-49f6-b7f4-d85356c28600",
  "runId" : "d8ce0fad-db38-4566-9198-90169efeb2d8",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2017-08-15T07:28:27.077Z",
  "numInputRows" : 1,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.3050640634533252,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 2452,
    "getBatch" : 461,
    "queryPlanning" : 276,
    "triggerExecution" : 3278
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaSource[Subscribe[test1]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "test1" : {
        "0" : 19
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "test1" : {
        "0" : 20
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 1,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.3050640634533252
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink@3ec8a100"
  }
}
Query made progress: {
  "id" : "a5b1f905-5575-43a7-afe9-dead0e4de2a7",
  "runId" : "8caea640-8772-4aab-ab13-84c1e952fb77",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2017-08-15T07:28:27.075Z",
  "numInputRows" : 1,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.272108843537415,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 2844,
    "getBatch" : 445,
    "queryPlanning" : 293,
    "triggerExecution" : 3672
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaSource[Subscribe[test1]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "test1" : {
        "0" : 19
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "test1" : {
        "0" : 20
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 1,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.272108843537415
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink@6953f971"
  }
}
```

why I send 1 message ,then it has two different  result.

1. My main program problem is I should use Spark to cal data every particular 5 mins, like 00:00-00:05, 00:05-00:10 and so on. A day has 288 point to cal.
2. So my idea is to use structured streaming to filter particular data and that not filter is to store database,and next time to read database and structured streaming together
3. So I should listening every  batches to update my time to read databases.

Answer (score 0):

These two events are from different queries. You can see that the `id` and `runId` are different.

Comment: oh ,thanks,I have two writestream .   how to give a particular streaming add a listener